# Deployed ASP.NET Core website unable to call a deployed REST API with CORS enabled

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have a REST Web API deployed deployed in Azure (NET 6.0) that has CORS enabled at code level and at azure config level, as you can see below

```cs
// Add CORS services to the builder
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
               .AllowAnyMethod()
               .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ContactsDbContext>(options =>
        options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ContactsDB")));
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Here is the CORS configuration in Azure for that API
[image]

I have also deployed a ASP website .Net that is trying to call the REST Web Api mentioned above but is not working

The errors are CORS related but dont seem related to my API

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

<script> source URI is not allowed in this document: “https://js.monitor.azure.com/scripts/b/ai.2.min.js”. sitecore-mgg.azurewebsites.net:1:1
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://eastus-8.in.applicationinsights.azure.com//v2/track. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource.
```

What else do I need to configure to be able to call the REST API from the deployed Azure web site ? Are those errors related to the API not being called ?

Comment: I have updated the question, the code does not seem relevant for issue, since it seems to be a deployment issue (code works on localhost)

Answer (score 0):

The errors shown in the console area caused by the application Insights, I have disabled them since I don't really need them

The lack of connectivity between Site and API seems to be caused because of a hardcoded URL that was wrong

[image]